# How to use pdf format in android

Tags: android

can we create and write on pdf files in android.
I have tried itext library of java but it gives class not found exception please help.
**Update**

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
document.open();
addMetaData(document);
addTitlePage(document);
addContent(document);
document.close();
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It sets warnings to my importing packages.

Comment: are you sure you have set build path to the libraries you use?

Comment: yes i have added library into my build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the library, I mentioned earlier is deprecated. Below is one of the active one.

https://mupdf.com/

Comment: Can you explain why this Android-specific Pdf library didn't work?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yeah The links are not apt way of answering. But the question itself is vague. We need details for answering. Normally this (Class not found ) errors come because of library linking/ build path etc.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'd also add that comments like "I have tried all from Google search" really don't help in diagnosing the problem - has the OP even tried it? if so, we can probably help with the problems (if we know what they are) but without knowing what's been tried, it's a VERY broad question to answer - especially since everything in Google has apparently been tried